# Rails 4 - Selecting associated models via collection (similar to .NET Linq's .SelectMany())

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

Forgive me if this has already been asked (as I believe it has), but I couldn't find this exact issue (and it's very likely I'm not searching properly).

I have the following models:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :jobs
end

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :company
    has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :jobs
end
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is a list of tags by company, but I'm failing to figure out *how* (I should note that I'm pretty new to Ruby and Rails). I come from a .NET background, and with Linq I'd use something like `Company.Jobs.SelectMany(j => j.Tags)`.

I tried to do `Company.first.jobs.tags`, which fails with `NoMethodError: undefined method 'tags' for #<Job::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x892dca0>`, but strangely enough, if I run `Company.first.jobs.instance_methods` on a rails console, there **is** a :tags method. And this is what I get when I use the console's autocomplete:

[image: rails console]

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called 'has many through'.

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :jobs
  has_many :tags, through: :jobs
end
```

This is how you can go through an association (in this case `jobs`) to get to that association's association.

This way you can run `company.tags` on an instance of a company.

Comment: Just to clarify a little bit - the problem with your existing approach is that jobs is a collection, but you need to hit the method on individual instances. This would work with no adjustment: `Company.first.jobs.collect { |job| job.tags }`.

Comment: @BradWerth could you post your suggestion as an answer? It's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @ptd Thanks! It works like a charm!

Now I'm trying to do the inverse, but I have one inconsistency: Tags should be scoped by company (a given tag should be associated to jobs from the same company). Right now, my only option is to use `has_many :through` in the Tag class too.  
Is there any way to set it up so a Tag can only have (or belong to) one Company?

Comment: @RafaelSoares You'll probably have better luck getting an answer for the second part of your question by posting it as a new question...

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your existing approach is that jobs is a collection, but you need to hit the method on individual instances. This would work with no adjustment:

`Company.first.jobs.collect { |job| job.tags }`